# I want to skip 1st row of excel file and print from 2nd row onwards

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am fetching data from excel sheet and putting it in table.
**But my requirement is, I want to take data from 2nd row onwards and 1st row is the header for the user those who are submitting data.**
Please help.

With this code that I have, it is able to fetch data from 1st row onwards.

```
    $html="<table border='1'>";
for($i=0;$i<count($data->sheets);$i++) // Loop to get all sheets in a file.
{   
    if(count($data->sheets[$i][cells])>0) // checking sheet not empty
    {
    //echo "Sheet $i:<br /><br />Total rows in sheet $i  ".count($data->sheets[$i][cells])."<br />";
        for($j=1;$j<=count($data->sheets[$i][cells]);$j++) // loop used to get each row of the sheet
        { 
            $html.="<tr>";
            for($k=1;$k<=count($data->sheets[$i][cells][$j]);$k++) // This loop is created to get data in a table format.
            {
                $html.="<td>";
                $html.=$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][$k];
                $html.="</td>";
            }
            $data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][1];
            $eid = $eid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][1]);
            $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][2]);
            $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][3]);
            $ethnic = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][4]);
            $variety= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][5]);
            $tender = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][6]);
            $subtype = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][7]);
            $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][8]);
            $query = "insert into submit_form(name,lab,submission,title,patient,age,gender,ethnic,cancer,sample,instrument,instrumenttype,attach)  values('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['dept']."','".$_POST['submission']."','".$_POST['title']."','".$eid."','".$age."','".$gender."','".$ethnic."','".$variety."','".$tender."','".$subtype."','".$type."','1')";

            mysqli_query($connection,$query);

            $html.="</tr>";
        }
    }

}

$html.="</table>";
header("location: submit.php?success=1");

}
}
```

Comment: Try `for($j=2; ...)`

Comment: Exactly what @ksimka says, the `$j` variable controls the rows, set it to start with 2 and it should work.

Comment: Great .. !! .. @ksimka,  ... Yeah, it works .. !!

Comment: Thanks  @bas van stein.